# Android ScrollView adds extra padding on top and bottom of child imageview

Tags: android, emulation, imageview, scrollview

I have a problem with rendering a ScrollView. Essentially, the layout is fixed header and footer with a scrollview in the middle. The idea is that when the screen keyboard is activated for the content EditText the image can be scrolled if the height of the image is longer than the middle view.

In testing the layout, I've found that on my Android phone (Xperia X10 Android 1.6) there is a whole heap of padding added to the top and bottom of the ImageView.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how I can prevent this from happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Header -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:text="Share your photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStack"
            android:text="Stacks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- End Header -->


    <!-- Body -->
    <ScrollView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:background="#CCCCCC">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- End Body -->


    <!-- Footer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/caption"
            android:text="Type your caption"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/caption"
            android:background="#CCCCCC">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
                android:text="Share"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- End Footer -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found after some experimentation that adding the following syntax to my java code solved the problem:

```
    imgPreview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imgPreview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: Any explanation to why?

Comment: I'm getting this issue on a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView. Putting adjustViewBounds on my xml is not solving it. Is there a cause to this? I noticed that the padding added at the top is the height of the status bar and the padding in the bottom is the same height as the navigation bar

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe - Set the ScrollView's height to 0dp

Answer (score 28):

Just adding the following attribute to your ImageView XML description do the job:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: This helped me with a GridLayout whose ImageView children had extra top and bottom padding.

Answer (score 14):

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Use these properties in the scrollview.

Comment: Hi there, tried it out but neither seemed to make any difference. We're not talking about a few pixels. It's a few hundred. Even if I specify the pixel width and height of the ImageView it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: The Best Answer! `fillViewport` does the job and allowing the child layout to take up the requested space.

Answer (score 2):

you can set marginTop and bottom to a negative number for the child like this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp">


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```