# Android images over image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

i have an imageView on screen and i want to put another imageview that will appear in the bottom of the imageView (It is just like a little line), i align the line with the main imageView the problem is that it left a little margin between the main imageView and the line,

In the emulator it align perfect but in the device it let a little margin like paddingbottom and i dont know why

this is the screen

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_8473957photoscreen.jpg

The white zone with the text "Manolo" should be on the bottom but there is a little margin

And there is the Code(is all in a linearLayout vertical)

```
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/inferior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/superior"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fondonombretransparencia" />
```

Comment: can you edit your question and include a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: what is the layout you are using? linear or relative? if linear, which gravity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the 'adjustViewBounds' parameter as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830503/unwanted-padding-around-an-imageview):

```
<ImageView
  (...)
  android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

If set to true, the ImageView will adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable. This might solve the padding difference between your emulator and the physical device.