# Scale down ImageButton / ImageView without leaving space around

Tags: android

I have some problems resizing ImageViews and ImageButtons.

Let's say that I have a Layout that has a rectangular shape (I don't want to know if it is a horizontal or vertical rectangle) and a ImageButton that contains a transparent background and as ImageResource a square image.

I want to keep the button square, so I use `setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)` to stretch the button. It works well.

The problems come when the button needs to be **REDUCED** to fit the rectangular layout, instead of stretched: in that case, the image is reduced correctly, but the space reserved in the layout is the one that would be reserved by the image if I hade made it crop.

This is what I think that happens:

1. the image is put in the layout
2. the space in the layout is reserved
3. AFTER THIS the image is resized
4. if the space asked is increased, the layout is enlarged, otherwise nothing is done
5. as a consequence in the layout the image results rounded by A LOT of empty space if the image needed to be reduced.

The classical problem is: I have a layout that should contain one row with - say - six square buttons. IF the button size is larger than the height of the Horizontal LinearLayout, the buttons end to be distantiated with a lot of empty space, instead of touching them.

I tried using fixed sizes for the images, to force them resize before putting them in the layout, but this is not a solution for me. First of all I want it to be dynamic (ie: the layout could change size during the app lifetime and the images should follow that). Second of all, when I put the image into the layout it can easily happen that the layout is not set yet and its size returns zero.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the attribute

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to your image view element in your layout. You can have a look to the post [Unwanted padding around an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830503/unwanted-padding-around-an-imageview)