# Android crop imageview

Tags: android, image

There is my `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

I load image to this `ImageView` using `Picasso` library.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url)
                            .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                            .into(imageView);
```

There is problem that there is padding inside `ImageView` and loaded image.

There is image to show padding:
[image: Padding]

I use `.fit()` method to avoid this gap, but image stretches and quality losts.

(You can see that this dark-blue circles is ovals now)
[image]

The question is:
What should I do to avoid loosing quality of image and resize it directly to `ImageView`. I can't add `.centerCrop()` because left side of image is logical safe-zone. Also I can't change `layout_height="150dp"` because it will break all my layout.

Anyway thank you!

Comment: use a better quality image then

Answer (score 0):

Look at your ImageView:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

You are forcing the image to stretch to the width of its parent view (the screen maybe?). Try using `wrap_content` for the width and keeping the height the same. This may cause the image to shrink, but its up to your desired UX.

@stefs found that adding this:

`...android:adjustViewBounds="true" />`

would help. Check out the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830503/unwanted-padding-around-an-imageview).

If you want static image sizes, you may have to deal with the padding.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't helps to me, `android:adjustViewBounds="true" /` ignoring at all

Comment: @VLeonovs did you try changing the width to `wrap_content` too?

Comment: Ok. Are these images square in shape or rectangular. I think the image is being stretched from what it is originally thats why it is like that. Post the original images so we can see em.