# Image view content not filling it self

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

here is my situation, I have an imageview like that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EyFr.png]

Can you see my "**+**" sign is not at the end of my "no profile picture" image, that's because this image is not filling its imageView.

I have tried `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` like was said in [Unwanted padding around an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830503/unwanted-padding-around-an-imageview), but it didn't work for me.

Any idea?

EDIT:

I forgot my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_no_image_profile"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_new_image_profile"
        android:background=""
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_profile_picture"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using any type of image loader libraries, make sure it is not overriding the scale type you set in the xml layout

Comment: @MuchOverflow I guess I'm not using any library to load that images

Comment: you should use drawable folder to place your image files. mipmap folder should be only used to place your app launcher icon files. Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/3533289 I think that might be the problem

Comment: may b it's your image that contains padding.

Comment: @umerk44 I don't think so, I have tried another images, and I got the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

**Remove** `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` from your **xml**.

Your xml code should looks like below:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_no_image_profile"
        />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It didn't work here, the image didn't fill the imageview

Comment: @guisantogui, can you please change src to background ?

Comment: I did that, but it didn't change the image behavior. :(